# short circuit onchange="submit()"

Tags: javascript

As the title states, I would like to short circuit the onchange (inside of a select).  I have the following code but I would just like to send a hard-coded value without ever showing the selection box.

```
<SELECT name="select_applet_instance" onchange="submit()">
     <% for (int i = 0 ; i <serviceBean.getinfo().size() ; i++){%>
     <OPTION value="<%=i%>"><%= serviceBean.getinfo().get(i) %></OPTION>
     <% }%>
</SELECT>
```

[edit]
Sorry, I was not clear.  I don't even want to offer a selection, I know what value I want to submit, I want to set that value and just forward the page
[/edit]

Comment: definitely check out this [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review"). It's almost there, just needs a little more support :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to show anything at all but redirect the user immediately:

```
<input type="hidden" value="4" name="select_applet_instance" />
<script>yourformhere.submit()</script>
```

Now the moment the browser reads the `<script>` tag, it will submit the form.

Comment: I want to replace everything in the SELECT with the redirect (the page was used for two things, prompting for data and getting input and then prompting for data.  In the latter case (my case) the redirect disables a couple of fields - that's my use case - I know the value to insert for OPTION, so when they display this page in that case, just forward it.

Comment: When I forward the value, I also need to set 'select_applet_instance' so that it can be read by the receiving page.

Comment: That seems to nearly do it - but the error is on my side, not your answer. Thanks a million/accepted!

Comment: this is a dirty hack though - you should probably rethink the application a bit - why does your user need to pass via this page if all it does is redirect? Put the logic in the page before, and have it redirect to the correct page from the first time. Also, code in plain `<script>` tags is not the way to go - it should probably wait until the DOM finished loading. Oh well, since it works...

Comment: I couldn't agree with you more. It's because of a change in usage of the page (no longer do we need the selection/input, we just need the input).

Answer (score 1):

You need to submit the form element.  You can do that by referencing the form and calling submit on it:

```
<SELECT name="select_applet_instance" onchange="document.getElementById('yourFormsID').submit()">
     <% for (int i = 0 ; i <serviceBean.getinfo().size() ; i++){%>
     <OPTION value="<%=i%>"><%= serviceBean.getinfo().get(i) %></OPTION>
     <% }%>
</SELECT>
```

Comment: Do you want to change the value of this select on form submission?

Comment: no, it's just a straight up forward - see Konerak's answer above